# Dokku on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu machine

Tags: openssl, dokku

I am trying to install [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) on Amazon EC2.
I've installed Dokku on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine.

Amazon provided me with a key pair used to connect to the machine via SSH as a key.pem file.

I converted this key to a .PPM private key with [PuttyGen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and now I am able to login to the server via SSH with Putty.

I installed Dokku on the machine which means it installed a GIT server (along with Docker and more).

When I try to push to this git server I get the following error :

> `* No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

1. How should I configure the client and/or server to allow git pushing?
2. Should I use the same key I received from Amazon or should I
   generate a new key pair ? and if so, how should I convert it ?

   - I am using a Windows client and have access to Mac OS/X as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the same keys for SSH and Dokku.
I exported the public key from Amazon AWS EC2 management console and imported it into the ssh deamon.

This way I could logon to SSH and Dokku(git server) with the same private key without the need to use multiple keys in the same session.

Thank you [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680728/felix) for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot answer your question directly, but mainly I can help you pointing you to a setup such that you can use the various useful tutorials out there (for some reasons there is quite some information out there about how to get started on digital ocean).*

First of all, according to the dokku documentation you will need **Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit**.

Then I would definately **create your own keys** (on your own machine).

To get around and play, why dont you setup (Linux) Virtual Machines on your Windows (or Mac OSX) box? One to have a proper shell and tools, the other one running dokku? Like this you have much more freedom in playing around with the systems in contrast to using your AWS.